# How many solutions for $a+b+c+d+e=10$ when $a$ is odd

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So I tried to solve this question and I got an answer and I'm not sure its right.

$a$ must be odd and $b,c,d,e \in \mathbb N$ (including zero).

How many solutions there is for the equation $a+b+c+d+e=10$ ?

so I divided it to parts where $a=1,3,5,7,9$.

when $a=1$ there is $\mathsf C_9^4$ options , $a=3 : \mathsf C_7^4$ , $a=5 : \mathsf C_5^4$ , $a=7 : \mathsf C_3^4$ , $a=9 : \mathsf C_1^4$.

so the amount of options is the sum of this options? Am I right or I did a mistake somewhere?

Comment: When $a=9$ there should be 4 solutions. Yet $_1C_4=0$. So something, somewhere, has gone wrong. But overall your approach (split into cases, add together the possibilities in each case) is sound.

Comment: When $a = 1$ and you do $9C4$, that will give you any $4$ numbers out of $9$ numbers, not necessarily they add to $10$. Also keep in mind - why not $10C4$? $b, c, d, e$ can be $1$ as well. Also you mention $0$ is allowed. Also you do not mention they all have to be different so you could have $1, 2, 2, 2, 3$ or $1, 0, 0, 0, 9$ or $1, 1, 0, 0, 8$.

Comment: @MathLover The number of natural number solutions to $b+c+d+e=9$ with no other restrictions is indeed best described by a binomial coefficient. Your examples included. I suspect the OP is attempting this standard solution, but missed a step. It should really be $\binom{9+4-1}{9}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you were trying to count the number of solutions using the so-called *stars and bars* method, it is somewhat misapplied.

Take the $a=1$ case, for instance. Then we must count the number of solutions to $b+c+d+e=9$. Applying stars and bars, there are $9$ stars (the right-hand side), and $4-1=3$ bars (the number of variables). They can be ordered in $$\binom{9+3}{9}$$ different ways, and this is also the number of possible solutions.

Correct all the other cases similarly, and add them all up in the end. Then you should have your answer.

Comment: oh ok , Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We have $b+c+d+e = 10 - a$. So we have $10 - a$ items, and can put three separators between them. Then we have $a$ be the number of items before the first separator, $b$ be the number of items between the first and second separator, $c$ - between the second the third, and $d$ - after the third separator.

Since the numbers can be 0, we allow separators before or after all items, and allow multiple separators between the same two items.

This means we have three separators and $10 - a + 1$ positions for them. Finally, they're with replacement.

Thus, for $a=1$, you have $C^R(10, 3) = C^3_{12}$.

Similarly, for $a=9$, you have $C^R(2, 3) = C^3_4 = 4$, as noted in the comment.

Comment: oh ok Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
By $\ds{\underline{definition}}$, the answer is given by:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{a = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{a\ \mbox{odd}}
\sum_{b = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{c = 0}^{\infty}
\sum_{d = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{e = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{z^{10}}
z^{a + b + c + d + e}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{10}}\sum_{a = 0}^{\infty}z^{2a + 1}
\pars{\sum_{b = 0}^{\infty}z^{b}}^{4}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{10}}{z \over 1 - z^{2}}
\pars{1 \over 1 - z}^{4} =
\bracks{z^{9}}\pars{1 + z}^{-1}\pars{1 - z}^{-5}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{k = 0}^{9}\bracks{z^{9}}\pars{-1}^{k}z^{k}\pars{1 - z}^{-5} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{9}\pars{-1}^{k}\bracks{z^{9 - k}}\pars{1 - z}^{-5}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\sum_{k = 0}^{9}\pars{-1}^{k}\bracks{z^{k}}\pars{1 - z}^{-5} =
-\sum_{k = 0}^{9}\pars{-1}^{k}{-5 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k} =
\\[5mm] = &
-\sum_{k = 0}^{9}\pars{-1}^{k}{k + 4 \choose 4}
=
\bbx{\Large 420} \\ &
\end{align}